# Enter value from String to wchar variable in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I assign a com port using the following line of code:

```
const wchar_t* mccommport = L"COM5";
```

then I can call mccommport if I need to use it. This works perfect. However I want to now pull what COM port to use from a label. How can I do this? In other words:

```
QString mccommport_string = ui->label_commport->text(); //Value here is COM5
const wchar_t* mccommport = mccommport_string ; //????? obviously this doesn't work.
```

How can I accomplish the above?

I have tried the following without success:

```
wchar_t array[5];
QString mccommport_string = "COM5"
mccommport_string.toWCharArray(array);
const wchar_t* mccommport = array;
const wchar_t* mccommport2 = L"COM5";
qDebug() << mccommport_string << mccommport << mccommport2;
```

The qDebug output it gives is:

```
"COM5" 0x15cd542 0xe814a2
```

If I try to communicate with the serial port using mccommport2 it works, if I try using mccommport it doesnt. I am a novice in c++ so I am not sure if these should be the same ... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the [QString::toWCharArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toWCharArray).

Comment: Have tried it without any luck @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Define "without any luck". What did you get?

Comment: @Unimportant see edit.

Comment: While skimming trough QT documentation: 1) `QString::toWCharArray` does not add 0-terminator at end of string. 2) I could not find an overload for `qDebug`'s operator `<<` that takes a wchar_t*, perhaps qDebug just can't print it?

Comment: perhaps. So any ideas on a solution? @Unimportant

Comment: @Scientized : If qDebug has no support for `wchar_t` there is nothing to fix (beside 0-terminating the result of `toWcharArray`). `mccommport` and `mccommport2` do contain the string you want, qDebug just can't print it correctly. You can try `std::wcout << mccommport << mccommport2 << std::endl;`. For me, `cout/wcout` output also shows up in qtcreator's application output window.

Comment: @Unimportant That is just the output to get some insight on what is going on - the qdebug part is superfluous. When I say it doesnt work I mean I cant communicate with the COM5 if I use the string.

Comment: @Scientized : Because of the missing 0-terminator. `mccommport_string.toWCharArray(array); array[mccommport_string.size()] = 0;`

Comment: @Unimportant still doesnt work properly. Meaning, I cant communicate with COM5 if I take the value from the Qstring. So frustrating....

Comment: What does the L do in front of "COM5"? Maybe this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way to get `QString` data into `const wchar_t*` is to use [`toStdWString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdWString) method:

```
QString mccommport_string = "COM5";
std::wstring com5_str(mccommport_string.toStdWString());

const wchar_t* mccommport = com5_str.c_str();
```

> What does the L do in front of "COM5"?

It means [wide string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).